# Can I use direct2d hardware-acceleration in serverside scenarios?

Tags: hardware-acceleration, direct2d, off-screen

Browsing through [direct2d resources](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/directx/archive/2009/09/11/using-direct2d-for-server-side-rendering.aspx) it seems hardware-acceleration is **not** available for server-side scenarios.

My requirement is to render images off-screen. While this is easy to achieve using WicBitmapRenderTarget it isn't hardware-accelerated. Is there away to achieve this using Direct2d?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do off-screen rendering with hardware acceleration is to allocate an IDXGISurface with DXGI, then use ID2D1Factory::CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget() to render to it.

Unfortunately, I think this still won't work for a server, since services run in session 0 which doesn't allow hardware acceleration. I'm hazy on the specifics.

The other "unfortunately" is that working with DXGI resources is much more complex than anything in Direct2D. Lots of "paperwork" to fill out and stuff.